# How can I put my TH next to TD when media screen becomes 787px? Is it possible?

Tags: html, css

I wanted some of my Td (the first two numbers from the bottom) to have "PRICE" and "TOTAL PRICE" name labels next to them when the media screen becomes 787px for example, Price: 20USD and TOTAL PRICE: 40USD. But I couldn't figure out how to do it. I tried to change TABLE and Th position but it didn't work. I was thinking if I have to use span tag. If you have any suggestions or ideas, please tell me what to do.

Thank you.

```
        <table>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="2">Product Details</th>  
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Total</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="img/bonsai1.jpg" alt=""  height=150 width=200></img></td>
                <td>Lorem Ipsum<br>
                    asdhakshdk aksjdaljksfla
                </td>
                <td><input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="10"></td>
                <td>20 USD</td>
                <td>40 USD</td>

                <td><button class="table-button">DELETE</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="img/flower4.jpg" alt=""  height=150 width=200></img></td>
                <td>Lorem Ipsum<br>
                    asdhakshdk aksjdaljksfla
                </td>
                <td><input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="10"></td>
                <td>20 USD</td>
                <td>40 USD</td>
                <td><button class="table-button">DELETE</button></td>
            </tr>
```

Here's the whole code: https://codepen.io/jujuju12/pen/NWYjxoM

Answer (score 0):

Add a span before the pricing that is hidden on bigger resolutions and show it on smaller resolutions.

```
<td><span class = "show_on_mobile"></span>20 USD</td>
.show_on_mobile {
    display: none;
}
@media(max-width: 787px) {
    .show_on_mobile {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```